# HTML5 Canvas + Subscript and Superscript

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to fill text in canvas as Subsccript and Superscript options. How do I acheive this.

Please help.

Comment: Is it only numbers that you want to sub/superscript?

Comment: I would like to add Text in superscript and numbers in subscript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you aren't allowed to use HTML in `drawText` you can't use `<sup>` and `sub`. Instead have to do it yourself.

In other words, when you want superscript you will need to change the font to be smaller and either draw the text at a higher y-position or else set `textBaseline = "top"`. For subscript you will have to do similar.

Otherwise you can use unicode. For instance it is valid to write:

`ctx.fillText('x₂', 50, 50);`, `ctx.fillText('normalText0123₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉', 50, 50);`, etc.

Comment: expanding on the unicode, it is ok to write something like `ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(178),50,50)`, which stands for superscript 2 &#178;

Comment: For completeness: Subscript: ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉  and Superscript: ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹

Answer (score 5):

The answer and comments are perfect, I wanted to add that you can easily convert numbers to subscript ones by shifting the character code by 8272, which corresponds to the difference between the char code for "₀" (code 8320) and that for "0" (code 48).

For example:

```js
var text = "N1234567890";

function subNums(str)
{
    var newStr = "";
  
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
        //  Get the code of the current character
        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code >= 48 && code <= 57)
        {
            //  If it's between "0" and "9", offset the code ...
            newStr += String.fromCharCode(code + 8272);
        }
        else
        {
            //   ... otherwise keep the character
            newStr += str[i];
        }
    }
  
    return newStr
}

//  Get the context
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

//  Write the string
ctx.font = "20px serif";
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 20);
ctx.fillText(subNums(text), 0, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='200' height='50'></canvas>
```

It's obviously just a quick example that converts all numbers to subscript, not necessarily what you'd always want!

Something more useful may be to convert a numerical value to a subscript directly, you can loop through all digits and create a string with characters between "₀" (code 8320) and "₉" (code 8329):

```js
//  Numerical value to use as subscript
//  Don't start it with 0 otherwise it will be read as an octal value!
var index = 1234567890;

function toSub(value)
{
  var str = "";
  //  Get the number of digits, with a minimum at 0 in case the value itself is 0
  var mag = Math.max(0, Math.floor(Math.log10(value)));
  //  Loop through all digits
  while (mag >= 0)
  {
    //  Current digit's value
    var digit = Math.floor(value/Math.pow(10, mag))%10;
    //  Append as subscript character
    str += String.fromCharCode(8320 + digit);
    mag--;
  }
  return str;
}

//  Get the context
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

//  Write the string
ctx.font = "20px serif";
ctx.fillText("N" + index, 0, 20);
ctx.fillText("N" + toSub(index), 0, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='200' height='50'></canvas>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the function `sub()`, for instance:

```js
var string = "2";
document.write("x" + string.sub());
document.write("  y" + string.sup());
```