# Rendering HTML styled text in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML like this: `3(5 + 9n<sup>2</sup>)`.  I also have some code that will show arrows going from the 3 to the 5 and the 3 to the 9n<sup>2</sup>.  I'm basically showing the distributive property (think **math** here).

Problem: I need to use `3(5 + 9n<sup>2</sup>)` as a javascript variable and instead of looking like this **3(5 + 9n<sup>2</sup>)** it looks like this **`3(5 + 9n<sup>2</sup>)`**.  This fiddle will show what I'm asking about more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/dTaMa/

Is there a way for javascript to "render" HTML?

Comment: *Rendering HTML into a JavaScript variable* does not make any sense.  You need to *render* HTML into a canvas. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: Protip: When a function is called "draw ***Text***", it won't handle HTML.

Comment: If it helps, you could look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: please see [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326191/html5-canvas-subscript-and-superscript

You can't use HTML markup with filltext, you will have to draw your text in two steps (in this case), first draw the non-superscript text, then another call to filltext to draw the suprtscript text at a different position with a different font size.

Comment: (I deleted my comment earlier as I misunderstood the question. I have changed the title to reflect the meaning of the question)

Comment: @Joe I think both the title (which you've fixed) and content need fixed/explained more (not your job, but fixing the title was great)

Comment: Here's an example using the link I posted: http://jsfiddle.net/u7hCe/

Comment: @hnafar: This seems like the most versatile solution.  I have no idea of how to do this though.  I'd also like to put everything in the "phrase" variable if possible.

Comment: @gtilflm it depends on how complicated your markup potentially is, for example if you know the only HTML tag you use is the SUP, then you can simply split your string into multiple parts, where the contents of each SUP are a separate part, and draw all parts of the string one after the other.

Comment: Off the top of my head, for a more complicated markup you can use jquery (or any other framework - or even just pure javascript if you feel comfortable enough with it which seems like you do) to create a DOM element containing the entire markup, then traverse the element and draw the text of each element based on its element name, though you would have to manually handle the case for each type of element, e.g. b, i, sup, sub, etc. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var phrase = "3(5 + 9n"+String.fromCharCode(178)+")";
```

For other codes see:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Unicode/Superscripts_and_Subscripts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

http://jsfiddle.net/dTaMa/1/

to get code for other values;

click on the corresponding link in *'Official designation'* column in that wiki appendix page (link provided above courtesy of @Joe) , then scroll down and use the *'HTML Entitiy (decimal)'* value under *'Encodings'*.

Comment: Good, but I want to be able to use exponents other than 2.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding those links, @rps. This does seem like it could be a useful and simple solution if it does what gtilflm needs.

Comment: I agree that this is an easy solution and I'm trying to make it work.  It doesn't seem to like the unicode characters though.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/dTaMa/2/

Comment: You should use escape sequences in your JS not the actual glyph.

Comment: `HTML Entity (decimal) &#8309;` use 8309 for super script 5! click on the link in _Official designation_ column in that wiki appendix page, then scroll down and use the HTML Entitiy (decimal) value under _Encodings_.

Comment: Actually, if these can be achieved with HTML entities I'll probably go that route.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Canvas cannot render HML so you either have to write drawing code to set a smaller font size and different baseline, or use Unicode.

If you don't want to copy and paste unicode you could write a method that converts a certain number to it's unicode value using `String.fromCharCode(178)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, of course it's possible to render html via javascript. The issue is, that's not your question. Your question is whether it is possible to render html within a canvas element: [here's your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335383/render-html-in-canvas-webgl), for which the summary is: not really, but there are workarounds.